# Angular 11 - Loading's delays for lazy loading module and SVG loading file

Tags: angular, lazy-loading

I'm using angular for an application with multiple modules, and I'm using lazy loading based on routing.

But when I navigate to trigger the loading of modules, I must wait 2sec to see the router-outlet be filled by routing target view.

I don't understand why this time is so long, for the moment the UI is almost empty without a lot of binding or anything..

Also, when I conditionally display an icon .svg, the time is also very long to load this one (2 sec).

The related code is :

```
<img *ngIf="isHidden"
             (click)="hideChildrens()"
             viewBox="0 0 24 24" [src]="'assets/plus.svg'">
        <img *ngIf="!isHidden"
             (click)="hideChildrens()"
             viewBox="0 0 24 24" [src]="'assets/minus.svg'">
```

And SVGs are stored in the assets folder

See below the network time, I guess it's not normal...

[image: Delay]

If you have any idea, please let me know :)

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

Generally this happens for a couple of reasons. But the one i encountered a lot is due to multiple subscriptions and not destroying them.

In angular we have a life-cycle hook for destroying called `ngOnDestroy()`. In this method, it is always preferred to destroy any subscriptions you might have.

Also use of RxJS. You can use some RxJS pipes to take care of some functionalities in the subscriptions, like, `pipe, of, filter, mergeMap, concatMap, combineLatest, map, take, takeUntil, etc` to manipulate the subscriptions too.

One more reason might be because excessive usage of code in methods like ngOnInit(). The more code you have, the more time angular takes to render the HTML.

These are some of the observations not all. So you may want to check them out.